# nanoScroller and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to use the nanoScroller JS script, and it works on Chrome and Firefox except in IE9. I don't know the problem, 'cause I've made a test in a teste page and it works, but in my project it doesn't work. Here it goes the script:

```
$(".lista-noticia").click(function () {
    $(".noticia-completa:visible").hide("slow");
    if ($(this).closest("li").find(".noticia-completa").is(':visible')) {
        $(".noticia-completa").hide("slow");
        $(".lista-noticia").removeClass("ativo");
    } else {
        $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("ativo").find(".noticia-completa").slideToggle(1200, function(){
           $(this).nanoScroller();
        });
        $(".lista-noticia").not(this).removeClass("ativo");
     }
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="noticia-completa nano">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.....</p>
        <img src="images/index/foto-noticia.png" alt="Imagem Noticia">
        <p>Donec non egestas magna....</p>
        <p>Donec non egestas magna....</p>
        <p>Donec non egestas magna....</p>                         

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your `<pre>` tags are a little bit confusing as there is a `</div>` outside of the first set and several `</pre>` missing from the second set.

Comment: I'v corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

IE up to 9 accepts only 4095 style rules per file, maybe thats the problem.

see also:
[Rails asset pipeline solution for IE 4096 selector/stylesheet limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126118/rails-asset-pipeline-solution-for-ie-4096-selector-stylesheet-limit)