# ie8/9 4096 css selector issue rails

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-4

Does anyone know of any rails 4 solutions for the ie 9/8 4096 css selector limit. I have tried the css-splitter gem, however I cannot get it to work in production. Any useful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails asset pipeline solution for IE 4096 selector/stylesheet limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126118/rails-asset-pipeline-solution-for-ie-4096-selector-stylesheet-limit)

Comment: I have tried this solution but doesn't seem to work in production, only works in development

Comment: well if it works in dev, then it works. You need to find out what's different about your production environment that stops it working there. You've got a workable solution, so make it work rather than trying to find another solution (because even if you do find another solution, what makes you think you won't have the same problem in production with that as well?)